# SOAP: HTTP Not Found when parameter is "SELECT sth FROM"!

Tags: php, sql, database, soap, prestashop

I' ve a problem with Soap (I'm using it for the first time!).
I'm trying to solve a problem with SOAP, used to communicate between my site and another.
In SoapServer (on my site) I have a function called say_hello() that takes no argument and returns simply "hello", if I call it from a SoapClient, also with an argument, it works well.
The problem appears if the argument passed is "SELECT everythingyouwanthere FROM otherthingifyouwant". I don't know why but it returns "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Not Found" (404 error).

This started to happen suddenly (or, at least, I don't know the causes). On the server PrestaShop is installed.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. Sorry for my bad english!

Answer (score 0):

try to pass the argument through an array.

Instead of

```
...
$client = new SoapClient(WSDL);
$client->say_hello("SELECT everythingyouwanthere FROM otherthingifyouwant");
...
```

try

```
...
$client = new SoapClient(WSDL);
$client->say_hello(array("parameter_name" => "SELECT everythingyouwanthere FROM otherthingifyouwant"));
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it doesn't work! Maybe because it isn't in WSDL mode?